# UTC conversion is different between local and server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5 app.
In this app I have a query that checks if an Event is already in the database. This works perfectly locally but not on the server. The problem, as I see it is that I convert the date I want to check into UTC and then do the query. The strange thing is that the output of the conversion is different between local and server for the exact same date.

**This is the query**

```
scope :available_holidays, -> (date) { where("events.starts_at > ? AND events.starts_at < ? AND ttype = ?", date.beginning_of_day, date.end_of_day, TYPE_NATIONAL) }
```

**This is how I convert to UTC**

```
Time.parse(holiday[:date].to_s).utc
```

**This is the output locally**

```
2017-12-31 00:00:00
```

**This is the output on the server**

```
2018-01-01 00:00:00
```

**This is my method in the controller**

```
def holidays
        output = []
        from = Date.civil(params["year"].to_i,1,1)
        to = Date.civil(params["year"].to_i,12,31)
        holidays = Holidays.between(from, to, params["country"])
        holidays.each do |holiday|
            date = Time.parse(holiday[:date].to_s).utc
            event = Event.available_holidays(date).count
            if event == 0
                output.push(holiday)
            end
        end
        render json: output.to_json
    end
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a number of possible problems.

```
holidays.each do |holiday|
  date = Time.parse(holiday[:date].to_s).utc
```

- Why is `Holidays.between` returning hashes rather than objects?
- Why is `holiday[:date]` a string and not a Date object?
- Why is a *date* being parsed with `Time.parse`?
- Why are time zones involved with a *date*?

The first two are structural problems. The second two I think are the real problems. Dates don't have time zones.

When you run, for example, `Time.parse("2018-05-06")` Ruby will return a `Time` for midnight at that date with a time zone. For example...

```
> Time.parse("2018-01-01")
=> 2018-01-01 00:00:00 -0800
> Time.parse("2018-01-01").utc
=> 2018-01-01 08:00:00 UTC
```

As a `Date` that's `2018-01-01` so no harm. But if you were in +0100...

```
> Time.parse("2018-01-01 00:00:00 +0100").utc
=> 2017-12-31 23:00:00 UTC
```

As a `Date` that's `2017-12-31`.

Don't convert dates to times and back to dates. Just keep them as dates.

```
holidays.each do |holiday|
  date = Date.parse(holiday[:date])
```

Better yet, have `Holidays` store `holiday[:date]` as a `Date` object.